# Should I add Backpack-installed Front-end Assets to Source Control?

Tags: laravel, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, laravel-artisan, laravel-backpack

I'm following the installation docs for Backpack 4.1 for Laravel. The `backpack:install` Artisan command adds front-end assets to the `/public/packages` directory of my project. Usually, front-end package managers (NPM, Yarn, Bower, etc.) recommend not to add the actual package contents to a project's repository, and instead add a dependency lockfile that can be re-installed by a CI/CD pipeline. Backpack does this differently, as it pulls the front-end dependencies directly and there was no mention if one needs to add `/public/packages` to source control. Should I add these package assets to source control, or should I execute `php artisan backpack:install` in the CI/CD process instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you should include the public/packages directory in your source control. That’s what Backpack assumes you’ll do.

However, if you would rather NOT do that, you can create an alias to the directory in the package. You can find instructions on how to do that here, as method 3 - https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tips-and-tricks/once-in-a-while-re-publish-backpack-s-css-and-js-assets

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why you might want to do commit the public assets to the source control:

- You may not have write access to your production file system.
- You may be deploying to more than one server, and want to avoid duplication of work.
- You may be doing frequent deploys that do not include asset changes.

Generally, I think it is a good idea to put precompiled assets into source control unless you have a specific reason not to do so.